# Bind variable to interface type in FSI

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, fsi

I'm experimenting with integration of F# as scripting language and have an issue with `FsiEvaluationSession.AddBoundVariable` method. Problem is that this method creates variable of actual type of object, but I need to create variable of interface that it implements. I can't find `AddBoundVariable<T>(string, T)` or any other overload that would allow be do that.

```ml
// located in common assembly
type IFoo =
    abstract Foo : unit -> unit

type FooImpl() =
    interface IFoo with
        member _.Foo () = ()

// located in host
session.AddBoundVariable ("foo", Foo())

session.EvalInteraction "foo.Foo()" // throws, `FooImpl` type doesn't have `Foo` method

session.EvalInteraction """
let foo : IFoo = foo
foo.Foo()
""" // throws, `IFoo` not found
```

Question is: how can I create variable of type that I want?

Answer (score 2):

You have to explicitly cast the `Foo` instance to `IFoo`, so this should work:

```
session.EvalInteraction """
let foo = foo :> IFoo
foo.Foo()
"""
```

To avoid the indirection of FSI, you can try this in your compiled code by simply binding `foo` as normal first:

```
let foo = FooImpl()
let foo : IFoo = foo    // ERROR: This expression was expected to have type 'IFoo' but here has type 'FooImpl'
let foo = foo :> IFoo   // works fine
foo.Foo()
```

Comment: The problem was that `session.AddBoundVariable` add variable but doesn't add library to compilation context. I had to explicitly add library with `session.EvalInteraction """#r "CommonLib.dll""""` and then it works. Still thanks!

Comment: That's good to know, but is a different problem from the question you asked. Anyway, I'm glad you were able to figure it out.